# Created a Walled Garden with WiFi Hotspot

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I want to create a WiFi Hotspot that can only access either a few files on my Android or a webpage run on my Android. This is so that when I am playing at gigs i can offer my music for free to people who connect. I know I can do this on a Windows machine but don't really want to drag around a laptop to every gig considering the amount of instruments, etc., that need to be transported.

I was hoping I could just set up a WiFi Hotspot and a walled garden so that when people connected it would force them to a page stating there is no internet connection only news and music by my band.

Has anyone got any ideas how this could be achieved or if I am being blind and there's an app that will already do it? (I have spent the last 3 days researching but so far I have not found much.)

Comment: Wi-Fi hotspot just gives you networking service. It doesn't automatically share your files. You need to use a kind of file server which could restrict sharing to few files.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to try [KWS Android Web Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xeustechnologies.android.kws&hl=en)

This is like LAMP, XAMPP, WAMP but for Android

This is not a simple file server, you need to create a webpage first to make it work.